# Contourplot with 2 different step sizes in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

This question has probably a totally simple solution but I just can't find it. I'd like to plot a contourf plot where the one part of my data varies in steps of order 1 and the other part varies with steps of order 100. 
Now I tried to just give contour levels like this:

```
contour_levels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 100, 200, 300, 400]
```

However this leads to the result that the fist 11 levels all have the same color as matplotlib is somehow normalizing this to the maximum value. How can I make every level equally important in terms of my color map?

Thanks a lot HYRY, your answer solved my problem. This is what the plots look like bevore and after the implementation (I adjusted the levels a bit; data from the GOZCARDS team/NASA):
[image: Water vapor time series bevore]
[image: Water vapor time series after]

Comment: use logarithmic scale : [ log(x) for x in countour_levels]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `colors` argument:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

x, y = np.mgrid[-1:1:100j, 0:1:100j]

z = ... # your function

contour_levels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 100, 200, 300, 400]

cmap = pl.cm.BuPu
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, len(contour_levels)))
pl.contour(x, y, z, levels=contour_levels, colors=colors)
```

Answer (score 4):

I am a little wary of HYRY's solution as the mapping between the colors level can become arbitrary.  I would suggest using `LogNorm` instead which maps your values -> colors with a `log`.

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

x, y = np.mgrid[-1:1:100j, 0:1:100j]

z = ... # your function

contour_levels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 100, 200, 300, 400]

cmap = pl.cm.BuPu
pl.contourf(x, y, z, levels=contour_levels, norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm)
```

If you also use `vmin` and `vmax` you can explicitly control the limits of the normalization and ensure that the color scales match between graphs independent of what `levels` you use.